# How do i add an mp3 file to a react js file

Tags: reactjs, mp3

I'm trying to play a single mp3 file for my react js application.
However when I add a file path to my method its not recognizing it.
the mp3 is located within the application.

I placed the path in a variable then placed the variable into a html audio element.

how do i get my mp3 to play in in my file?

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";


const moby = require('../music/mobyPorcelain.mp3')
const Sound = new Audio(moby)


export default function Header()  {
  
  const [playInLoop, setPlayInLoop] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=> {
    Sound.load();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    Sound.loop = playInLoop
  },[playInLoop])

  const playSound = () => {
    Sound.play();
  }

  const pauseSound = () => {
    Sound.pause();
  }

const stopSound = () => {
  Sound.pause();
  Sound.currentTime = 0;
}
 

  
    return (
                  <div>
                    <h3>Moby porcelain</h3>
                    <input
                    type='button'
                    className='btn btn-primary mr-2'
                    value='play'
                    onclick={playSound}/>
                    <input
                    type='button'
                    className='btn btn-warning mr-2'
                    value='pause'
                    onclick={pauseSound}/>
                    <input
                    type='button'
                    className='btn btn-danger mr-3'
                    value='stop'
                    onclick={stopSound}/>
                    <label><input type='checkbox' checked={playInLoop} onChange={e => setPlayInLoop(e.target.checked)}/></label>
                  </div>
                  
    );
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my console looked like when I tried to debug your code:

[image]

refactor `onclick` into `onClick` and it should work

[image: Edit rough-worker-3znu5]

Comment: That was it. Thank you. sometimes its the smallest things